# Replace text in lines in a file with increments

Tags: unix

I have a file with multiple lines (no. of lines unknown)

```
DD0TRANSID000019021210504250003379433005533665506656000008587201902070168304000.0AK  0000L00000.00  N          01683016832019021220190212N0000.001683065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NAcknowledgment                                                                                                                                        
DD0TRANSID000019021210505110003379433005535567606656000008587201902085381804000.0FC  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NFirst Contact                                                                                                                                         
DD0TRANSID000019021210510360003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NStatus Report
```

The text TRANSID000 is in every line starting from 3rd to 10th poisition
I need to be able to replace it with TRAN000066 in increments of 1

66 is a variable I am getting from another file (say nextcounter) for storing the start of the counter. Once the program updates all the lines, I should be able to capture the last number and update the nextcounter file with it.

Output

```
DD0TRAN00066019021210504250003379433005533665506656000008587201902070168304000.0AK  0000L00000.00  N          01683016832019021220190212N0000.001683065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NAcknowledgment                                                                                                                                        
    DD0TRAN00067019021210505110003379433005535567606656000008587201902085381804000.0FC  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NFirst Contact                                                                                                                                         
    DD0TRAN00068019021210510360003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NStatus Report
```

I have tried awk sed and perl, but it does not give me desired results.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use `sed` you might want to use a loop, avoiding the ugly

```
sed '=' inputfile | sed -r '{N;s/(.*)\n(.*)(TRANSID000)(.*)/echo "\2TRAN0$((\1+65))\4"/e}'
```

It is much easier with `awk`:

```
awk -v start=66 '{ sub(/TRANSID000/, "TRAN0" start++); print }' inputfile
```

EDIT:
OP asks for `replace TRANSID with TRAN0`, I showed this in the edited solution.
When I look to the example output, the additional `0` is not needed.
Another question is what happens when the counter comes above 99. Should one of the leading zeroes be deleted (with a construction like `printf "%.4d"`), or will the line length be 1 more?

```
DD0TRAN00099019...
DD0TRAN00100019...
# or
DD0TRAN00099019...
DD0TRAN000100019...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop

```
s=66; while read l; do echo "$l" | sed "s/TRANSID000/TRAN$(printf '%06d' $s)/" ; s=$((s+=1)); done < inputFile > outputFile; echo $s > counterFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Walter A answer is almost perfect, missing the required lines 3-10 limit.
So the improved answer is:

```
    awk -v start=66 'NR > 2 && NR < 11{ sub(/TRANSID000/, "TRAN0000" start++); print }' inputfile
```

Comment: 3-10 limit is not the line-number but the positions in each line. I did not use this in the solution, since the examples have the prefix `DD0`, so OP is counting from 0, has invalid testdata or wants from position 4. Just matching the string seems fine given the example input, so I ignored the starting position in the line. I did miss the replacement of `SID` by `0`, so I edit my solution.